# Auto print files inside a specific monitored folder to default printer (or send file via email)

Tags: printing, dropbox, network-printer

What I want to do is have a dropbox folder on my computer, which is monitored and any file which goes into the folder gets sent to my printer (and afterwards removed from the queue/folder).

Alternatively, if this is not possible - my printer supports HP eprint or google cloudprint, so could I have a folder monitored which automatically emails files inside of it to a specific address? (I use Thunderbird, but open to suggestions)

**edit:** Have just tried using [ITTT](http://ifttt.com/) to create a recipe to monitor dropbox folder and then send email automatically when new files are uploaded to the folder. This works ok, but you cannot share a folder as ITTT only has access to your public folders which cannot be shared. A good start though!

Comment: @techie007 Finding something to monitor a folder and print anything inside it is where i'm getting stuck. I'm currently trying an ITTT recipe - will answer if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved the problem by using **[wappwolf.com](http://wappwolf.com/)**

After linking both my dropbox account and my google account - it was able to specify a folder inside dropbox (including non public folders) and any file which goes in there can be set to auto convert to PDF and then send to google cloud print (using the printer of your choice).

The reason it converts to PDF first is because some file formats aren't handled by default (in my case docx) - but you don't have to PDF first if you don't want to.

Once the files are printed - they get moved into a folder inside your specified watch folder, called 'processed' - and any files which fail notify you via email

**Note:** You cannot share a folder if it is inside an app folder (so if you use the 'single folder access' when signing into wappwold, you will not be able to share the folder)